# Pandas Split rows based on different delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, split

So i currently have this :

```
s = final_df['Column Name'].str.split(';').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
```

which splits row when it finds the `;` delimiter. However, I will not always have the semicolon as my delimiter. Is there to incorporate `re.split` or other delimiters into `str.split`? Basically, there could be '`:`', '`;`' `,`'`|`' as my delimiters but I won't know.

I tried to just do `split(';', '|')` but I knew that wouldn't work.

Comment: Try `s = final_df['Column Name'].str.split(r'[;:|]').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()`.

Comment: Do you read the `DataFrame` from a `csv` file? If you do, you can specify the delimiter when reading the file [CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: it is from a CSV file, but i wouldnt know the delimiter before hand. i would like it to loop through the possibilities (; : |).

Answer (score 2):

`str.split` offers `regex` just like `re.split` does. So, you do need to use the latter. The following should do:

```
s = final_df['Column Name'].str.split(r'[;:|]').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
```

If the starting file contains those delimiters, you could actually provide the regular expression pattern to the `sep` parameter of the `read_table` function and set its `engine` parameter to `"python"`. The following uses the `io` module and a random string to illustrate the point:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


mystring = u"hello:world|123;here|we;go,again"
with io.StringIO(mystring) as f:
    df = pd.read_table(f, sep=r"[;:|,]", engine="python", header=None)

df
#        0      1    2     3   4   5      6
# 0  hello  world  123  here  we  go  again
```

This one split on `:`, `;`, `|` and `,`.

I hope this proves useful.